# Is it possible to use one map API for all platforms in Xamarin cross platform app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, xamarin

I want to dev a golf GPS app using Xamarin forms. I need to use mapping and have read documentation stating that you need to use the map from the play store for android and another source for iOS. I am really looking to write the logic once. Is there any mapping tool that can be used this way?

Comment: The basic answer is yes and no for an out-of-box solution. Forms' uses Google maps on Android, Apple Maps on iOS, and UWP uses Bing, so while Forms abstracts those into one common API, that API is fairly limited and ***if*** you need additional Map features then you need to implement those features in native "Map" code and map that back to your enhanced Forms' Map API abstraction. Even the native platform-based Google Map Apis for Android and iOS are different.

Comment: The common element within Google Maps is the REST-based API that the native platform APIs call (html/js, Android, iOS) so you could use that, but you would be building a solution from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SushiHangover